# Database design schema for a multi event competition, step 2 will be tracking the same data over multiple years

Tags: sql-server, database, schema

I am new to databases and I can't wrap my head around the schema I need.

I have a table for competitors, and a table for events. Each competitor will compete in each of the 8 events. I believe I need a bridge table, and I have looked at the student/class model. I believe my problem lies in the fact that I am trying to place each of the 10 scores inside the event table, but I don't know how to make the association between them.

Here is where I am at with my model:
[Click here for schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my1Zp.png)

Comment: What do `Score1` to `Score10` represent?

Comment: @mendosi Score1 to Score10 represent the actual points earned (think archery) by a competitor during the event.

Comment: So, each competitor gets ten scores in each event?

Comment: @mendosi Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, the `Score1` to `Score10` are pieces of information that relate to a specific competitor competing in an event, so those would rightfully belong in the bridge table.

You could also choose to have each score as a separate row in that bridge table, or to keep them all on a single row. You might choose to do the latter if you know that there will *always* be ten scores each time a competitor competes in an event.

So, your bridge table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EventCompetitor (
    EventID int NOT NULL,
    CompetitorID int NOT NULL,
    Round int NOT NULL,
    Score int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fEventID_EventCompetitor FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES Event(EventID),
    CONSTRAINT fCompetitorID_EventCompetitor FOREIGN KEY (CompetitorID) REFERENCES Competitor(CompetitorID),
    CONSTRAINT pEventID_CompetitorID_Round_EventCompetitor PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EventID, CompetitorID, Round));
```

So this way there would be ten rows to represent the ten scores that a competitor gets in the event and to find out the final score you just add all the scores:

```
SELECT EventID, CompetitorID, TotalScore = SUM(Score)
  FROM EventCompetitor;
```

The other option would be for the bridge table to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EventCompetitor (
    EventID int NOT NULL,
    CompetitorID int NOT NULL,
    Score01 int NULL,
    Score02 int NULL,
    Score03 int NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT pEventID_CompetitorID_EventCompetitor PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EventID, CompetitorID));
```

And your query to get the total score would be like this:

```
SELECT EventID, CompetitorID,
       TotalScore = ISNULL(Score01, 0) + ISNULL(Score02, 0) + ISNULL(Score03, 0) + ...
  FROM EventCompetitor;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now see that my bridge table needed the scores, and I understand why. I plan to submit all 10 scores from the UI at the same time, so I prefer the second option.